# Issue with dates after publishing on azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-hosting

i was running an app using local SQL hosting provider and everything was working fine (hosted in Australia).

I then decided to move MS Azure with an Australian region subscription.

There is now a very odd bug playing up and I cant work out which setting in MS Azure is causing it.

Basically:

- I use a drag and drop feature for my roster (drag and drop shifts on a specific day)
- If I drag a shift to a specific date, once you drop the shift it appears on the day before in my calendar
- The app always thinks that the date is the day before

The application works on my local before publishing.
It was working under my old hosting provider
After I migrated to Azure and publish, the issue shows on my live site (but not my local)

To make it more complicated, I actually connected my localhost to the MS Azure database directly to test - IT WORKS!

The issue only shows after publish.

It feels like it has to do with the regional settings on MS Azure and given that Australia is many hours ahead of the rest of the world, it feels like it is picking up the US time or the server time (which will almost always be the day before).

In Azure, my SQL server is hosted in east coast Australia as shown on my Azure dashboard.

Anyone experienced anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

> I actually connected my localhost to the MS Azure database directly to test - IT WORKS!

The default time zone of Azure WebApp is UTC, we could set the custom time zone for Azure WebApp. About how to change the server time zone on Azure Web Apps, we could get detail information from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/04/06/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps/). The following is the snippet from the blog.

> All you need to do is add an [Application Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) (via the portal or the management APIs) called `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` and set that to the name of the time zone as defined in the Windows Registry under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\ (for example, “AUS Eastern Standard Time”).

[image]